# Refine and fix the unused fixed parameter on the isar proof

Tags: isabelle

I am trying to refine the proof on the complete path proving as shown below:

```
lemma completePathProp:
  assumes a1:"p \<in> complete_Path a b"
  shows "(b \<in> bundles)  \<longrightarrow> unique_originate a n
         \<longrightarrow> (\<forall> n'. ((n'\<in> nodes b) \<and> last p=n' \<longrightarrow>(n'=n | (n,n'):(edges b)^+)))" 
      (is "?cons1 p")
  and "p \<noteq>[]"  (is "?cons2 p")
  and "\<forall>m. m\<in>(set p)\<and>node_sign m=+ \<and> a\<sqsubset> node_term m 
        \<longrightarrow> 
       (\<forall>m'.(m'\<Rightarrow>\<^sup>+ m)\<and> a\<sqsubset> node_term  m'\<longrightarrow> m'\<in>(set p))"
      (is "?cons3 p")
using a1
proof (induction)
  fix m m2 p
  let ?p="p @ slice_arr_cons (strand m) (index m) (index m2 - index m)"
 
  show "?cons1 p \<and> ?cons2 p \<and> ?cons3 p "
```

But I meet the problem that isabelle can not refine the proof automatically that:

```
goal (9 subgoals):
 1. ⋀m2 m p.
       non_originate a (strand m2) ⟹
       node_sign m2 = + ⟹
       a ⊏  node_term m2 ⟹
       first_node_in_nonorigi_strand a m2 m ⟹
       p ∈ complete_Path a b ⟹
       b ∈ bundles ⟶ unique_originate a n ⟶ (∀n'. n' ∈ nodes b ∧ last p = n' ⟶ n' = n ∨ n ≺⇩b n') ⟹
       p ≠ [] ⟹
       ∀m. m ∈ set p ∧ node_sign m = + ∧ a ⊏  node_term m ⟶
           (∀m'. m' ⇒⇧+ m ∧ a ⊏  node_term m' ⟶ m' ∈ set p) ⟹
       last p = m ⟹
       b ∈ bundles ⟶
       unique_originate a n ⟶
       (∀n'. n' ∈ nodes b ∧ last (p @ slice_arr_cons (strand m) (index m) (index m2 - index m)) = n' ⟶
             n' = n ∨ n ≺⇩b n')
 2. ⋀m2 m p.
       non_originate a (strand m2) ⟹
       node_sign m2 = + ⟹
       a ⊏  node_term m2 ⟹
       first_node_in_nonorigi_strand a m2 m ⟹
       p ∈ complete_Path a b ⟹
       b ∈ bundles ⟶ unique_originate a n ⟶ (∀n'. n' ∈ nodes b ∧ last p = n' ⟶ n' = n ∨ n ≺⇩b n') ⟹
       p ≠ [] ⟹
       ∀m. m ∈ set p ∧ node_sign m = + ∧ a ⊏  node_term m ⟶
           (∀m'. m' ⇒⇧+ m ∧ a ⊏  node_term m' ⟶ m' ∈ set p) ⟹
       last p = m ⟹ p @ slice_arr_cons (strand m) (index m) (index m2 - index m) ≠ []
 3. ⋀m2 m p.
       non_originate a (strand m2) ⟹
       node_sign m2 = + ⟹
       a ⊏  node_term m2 ⟹
       first_node_in_nonorigi_strand a m2 m ⟹
       p ∈ complete_Path a b ⟹
       b ∈ bundles ⟶ unique_originate a n ⟶ (∀n'. n' ∈ nodes b ∧ last p = n' ⟶ n' = n ∨ n ≺⇩b n') ⟹
       p ≠ [] ⟹
       ∀m. m ∈ set p ∧ node_sign m = + ∧ a ⊏  node_term m ⟶
           (∀m'. m' ⇒⇧+ m ∧ a ⊏  node_term m' ⟶ m' ∈ set p) ⟹
       last p = m ⟹
       ∀ma. ma ∈ set (p @ slice_arr_cons (strand m) (index m) (index m2 - index m)) ∧
            node_sign ma = + ∧ a ⊏  node_term ma ⟶
            (∀m'. m' ⇒⇧+ ma ∧ a ⊏  node_term m' ⟶
                  m' ∈ set (p @ slice_arr_cons (strand m) (index m) (index m2 - index m)))
 4. ⋀m m2.
       unique_originate a m ⟹
       strand m2 = strand m ⟹
       a ⊏  node_term m2 ⟹
       node_sign m2 = + ⟹
       b ∈ bundles ⟶
       unique_originate a n ⟶
       (∀n'. n' ∈ nodes b ∧ last (slice_arr_cons (strand m) (index m) (index m2 - index m)) = n' ⟶
             n' = n ∨ n ≺⇩b n')
 5. ⋀m m2.
       unique_originate a m ⟹
       strand m2 = strand m ⟹
       a ⊏  node_term m2 ⟹ node_sign m2 = + ⟹ slice_arr_cons (strand m) (index m) (index m2 - index m) ≠ []
 6. ⋀m m2.
       unique_originate a m ⟹
       strand m2 = strand m ⟹
       a ⊏  node_term m2 ⟹
       node_sign m2 = + ⟹
       ∀ma. ma ∈ set (slice_arr_cons (strand m) (index m) (index m2 - index m)) ∧
            node_sign ma = + ∧ a ⊏  node_term ma ⟶
            (∀m'. m' ⇒⇧+ ma ∧ a ⊏  node_term m' ⟶
                  m' ∈ set (slice_arr_cons (strand m) (index m) (index m2 - index m)))
 7. ⋀m1 m2 p.
       m1 → m2 ⟹
       m1 ∈ nodes b ⟹
       (m1, m2) ∈ edges b ⟹
       p ∈ complete_Path a b ⟹
       b ∈ bundles ⟶ unique_originate a n ⟶ (∀n'. n' ∈ nodes b ∧ last p = n' ⟶ n' = n ∨ n ≺⇩b n') ⟹
       p ≠ [] ⟹
       ∀m. m ∈ set p ∧ node_sign m = + ∧ a ⊏  node_term m ⟶
           (∀m'. m' ⇒⇧+ m ∧ a ⊏  node_term m' ⟶ m' ∈ set p) ⟹
       a ⊏  node_term m2 ⟹
       last p = m1 ⟹
       b ∈ bundles ⟶ unique_originate a n ⟶ (∀n'. n' ∈ nodes b ∧ last (p @ [m2]) = n' ⟶ n' = n ∨ n ≺⇩b n')
 8. ⋀m1 m2 p.
       m1 → m2 ⟹
       m1 ∈ nodes b ⟹
       (m1, m2) ∈ edges b ⟹
       p ∈ complete_Path a b ⟹
       b ∈ bundles ⟶ unique_originate a n ⟶ (∀n'. n' ∈ nodes b ∧ last p = n' ⟶ n' = n ∨ n ≺⇩b n') ⟹
       p ≠ [] ⟹
       ∀m. m ∈ set p ∧ node_sign m = + ∧ a ⊏  node_term m ⟶
           (∀m'. m' ⇒⇧+ m ∧ a ⊏  node_term m' ⟶ m' ∈ set p) ⟹
       a ⊏  node_term m2 ⟹ last p = m1 ⟹ p @ [m2] ≠ []
 9. ⋀m1 m2 p.
       m1 → m2 ⟹
       m1 ∈ nodes b ⟹
       (m1, m2) ∈ edges b ⟹
       p ∈ complete_Path a b ⟹
       b ∈ bundles ⟶ unique_originate a n ⟶ (∀n'. n' ∈ nodes b ∧ last p = n' ⟶ n' = n ∨ n ≺⇩b n') ⟹
       p ≠ [] ⟹
       ∀m. m ∈ set p ∧ node_sign m = + ∧ a ⊏  node_term m ⟶
           (∀m'. m' ⇒⇧+ m ∧ a ⊏  node_term m' ⟶ m' ∈ set p) ⟹
       a ⊏  node_term m2 ⟹
       last p = m1 ⟹
       ∀m. m ∈ set (p @ [m2]) ∧ node_sign m = + ∧ a ⊏  node_term m ⟶
           (∀m'. m' ⇒⇧+ m ∧ a ⊏  node_term m' ⟶ m' ∈ set (p @ [m2])) 
Failed to refine any pending goal 
Local statement fails to refine any pending goal
Failed attempt to solve goal by exported rule:
  (b ∈ bundles ⟶ unique_originate a n ⟶ (∀n'. n' ∈ nodes b ∧ last ?pa2 = n' ⟶ n' = n ∨ n ≺⇩b n')) ∧
  ?pa2 ≠ [] ∧
  (∀m. m ∈ set ?pa2 ∧ node_sign m = + ∧ a ⊏  node_term m ⟶
       (∀m'. m' ⇒⇧+ m ∧ a ⊏  node_term m' ⟶ m' ∈ set ?pa2))
```

I found that there are total 9 subgoals on the lemma proving, and on the subgoal 5 and 6, parameter q is unused, is this cause the error, and how to fix it?

Comment: Without MWE, I guess that it should be `?cons1 ?p` instead of `?cons1 p`. And I don't know why you believe that your goal should be `?cons1 p & ?cons2 p & ?cons3p` instead of having 3 goals `?cons1 p`, `?cons2 p`, and `?cons3 p`.

Comment: And trick: `case (label n)  case 1  then show ?case sorry   case 2   then show ?case sorry` works for such cases